# Problem initializing private submodule in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-submodules

I have been trying for days without success. Hopefully somebody can help me.

I have a private repository (that I own) that has a private submodule (that I also own) and I am trying to use use gitlab CI to get my binaries, which is just a pdf from a latex build. The problem is that when the pipeline is triggered, I can not manage to access the submodule to initialise it. I have followed  [this documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/), namely adding private and public ssh keys, with no success.

Here is how my gitlab yaml looks like, taken from the documentation. I also added my variables and deploy keys(I tried in both the main repo and in the submodule)

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive:latest
default:
  before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

build_compendium:
  when: always
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive # Sometimes I add this, according to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html
  script:
    # I HAVE TRIED DIFFERENT THINGS HERE, LIKE git submodule, git clone, etc...
    - pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode main.tex
    - pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode main.tex
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - "main.pdf"
```

The errors that I mostly get is that I get asked for credentials, which I can not provide during the pipeline build, or I get a message saying that I dont have access to the  submodule.

I only know some basics about ssh protocols and how to connect to servers using it, but I might be missing out something.

Your help is very much appreciated.